# what preposition should I use for website visitors?

Tags: prepositions

Assume I am not a registered user and browsing ell. So I am just a visitor. what preposition should I use to express this meaning?

I am a visitor of ell.

or

I am a visitor on ell.

or

I am a visitor for ell.

Comment: I would use _to_, but _on_ would also work.

Comment: Bypass the problem: "I am visiting ELL."